# $J$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with all entries $1$ Then $J$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$J$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with all entries $1$ Then $J$ is

1. Diagonalizable
2. Positive semidefinite
3. $0,3$ are only eigenvalues of $J$
4. Is positive definite

$J$ has minimal polynomial $x(x-3)=0$ so 1, 2,3 are true , am I right?

Comment: You are indeed correct! I can add the actual answers to 1 if desired.

Comment: @Amzoti I am afraid about 1 as I have concluded mentally that as min poly has distinct roots with linear factors so it is diagonalizable. am I wrong?

Comment: see Julien's nice answer on this point. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti I think that Taxi Driver's computer does not display my answers.

Comment: @julien I am sorry I forgot to accept!

Comment: I was only kidding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. This is a multiple duplicate but I can't find any.

The matrix has rank $1$, which makes $0$ an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$. Then the trace tells us what the other eigenvalue is, whence diagonalizability, since it adds the missing dimension. Since $0$ is an eigenvalue, it can't be positive definite. But it is indeed positive semidefinite by diagonalization in an orthonormal basis ($J$ is symmetric, eigenvalues are nonnegative). The minimal polynomial is obvious by diagonalization.

Alternative: we can observe that $J^2=3J$ so $J$ is annihilated by $X^2-3X=X(X-3)$, which is therefore divided by the minimal polynomial. Since $J$ is nether $I_3$ nor $3I_3$, the latter must be the minimal polynomial. It splits and has simple roots. Whence 1 and 3.

Comment: you are quick! +1

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks. Not so much, it is just already the third time I diagonalize $J$ here. And I still don't know how to find duplicates...